# Problemas con el envio de un formulario dudas con el armado de PHP

Tags: php, php5, phpmailer

Estoy teniendo problemas con el armado de un PHP para un formulario en un sitio web, el problema es que no recibiendo los datos que estoy poniendo dentro de cada input. Queria saber si esta bien armado o si tengo que tener en cuenta algo para poder realizar dicha prueba. Por otro lado puede ser posible que tenga que configurar algo en mi cuenta de correo para que me lleguen? Porque probe con varias cuentas y no sucede nada.

```js
<?php
$remitente = $_POST['email'];
$destinatario = 'xxx@hotmail.com'; // en esta línea va el mail del destinatario, puede ser una cuenta de hotmail, yahoo, gmail, etc
$asunto = 'Consulta Bricsa'; // acá se puede modificar el asunto del mail
if (!$_POST){
?>

<?php
}else{
     
    $cuerpo = "Nombre: " . $_POST["nombre"] . "\r \n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Empresa: " . $_POST["empresa"] . "\r \n";
    $cuerpo .= "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r \n";
    $cuerpo .= "Telefono: " . $_POST["telefono"] . "\r \n";
    $cuerpo .= "Consulta: " . $_POST["consulta"] . "\r\n";


    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";
    $headers .= "From: \"".$_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['empresa']."\" <".$remitente.">\n";

    mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo, $headers);
    
    include 'confirmacion.html'; //se debe crear un html que confirma el envío
}
?>
```

```html
<form role="form" action="contacto.php" method="post">

  <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" type="text" name="nombre" />

  <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Empresa" type="text" name="empresa" />

  <input maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="contact-email" />

  <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono" />

  <textarea class="form-control" name="consulta" maxlength="1200" rows="4" placeholder="Dejanos tu consulta..."></textarea>

  <input class="btn" type="submit" name="" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

Comment: Procura evitar la conversión de tipos. Es una mala costumbre hacer una comprobación del tipo `if (!$_POST)` (además de dejar implícita la comprobación booleana) en vez de un `if (count($_POST) === 0)`. Así podrías darte cuenta que estás poniendo el `if` justo al revés.

Comment: entonces? como debería dejarlo? No conozco mucho de php este ejemplo lo tome de un curso que hice hace un tiempo, supuestamente funcionaba pero estuve probando y no me anduvo.

Comment: Disculpa, precisamente por hacer la comprobación así he confundido su interpretación. ¿Podrías decirme cómo sabes o qué síntomas tienes para saber que no te llegan los datos del formulario? ¿Simplemente es que no te llega el correo? ¿Usas un MTA local? ¿Es un servidor Windows? [¿Te funciona una llamada a la función `mail()` con los parámetros introducidos a mano en vez de a través de un formulario?](http://php.net/function.mail#refsect1-function.mail-examples)

Comment: En realidad yo este php lo habia usado en su momento en algunos proyectos y me funcionaba, me resulta muy raro que ahora lo quiera volver a usar y no me funcione. La idea es que me lleguen los datos que vinculo en el form y que lleguen a mi cuenta a modo de prueba.

Comment: ¿Ese código te funcionaba en el mismo servidor o alojamiento que el actual? ¿Has cambiado de alojamiento o de servidor? Ese código es altamente dependiente de la configuración del servidor, no sería portable de manera sencilla a muchos otros alojamientos. ¿Podrías, por favor, probar algún código de [ejemplo del manual de `mail()`](http://php.net/function.mail#refsect1-function.mail-examples) cambiando la dirección de correo por la tuya?

Comment: si en realidad ahora lo estoy probando en un servidor que supuestamente andaba bien por eso me resulta raro.

Comment: el sitio es este http://bric.com.ar/

Comment: Para no llenar esto de comentarios [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86391/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-mariano-andres-franco).

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez estoy preguntando lo obvio pero: ¿el archivo contacto.php es el que tiene el código php para enviar el correo? (El formulario envía los datos a ese archivo).

Adicionalmente, la forma en que yo hago la validación es ponerle un nombre (name) al botón "ENVIAR" y luego comprobar si esa variable existe (o sea, si has hecho click en ese botón):

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar']) {
    // Tu codigo aqui
}
```

También es bueno si no utilizas directamente las variables $_POST[], sino filtrarlas mediante filter_input():

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');    // En lugar de $_POST['email']
```

Comment: Hola Juan claro ese archivo contiene los datos de php. entonces vos decis que cambiando eso podria andar?

Comment: Como seria el armado Juan ya que yo de php no se mucho.